# Вопрос по MRO (порядок наследования) в Python

Tags: python, наследование

Приветстсую! Столкнулся с двумя интересными примерами наследования в Python. Со стороны кажется, что примеры идентичны (в плане иерархии последовательности), однако на деле поведение различно.
Первый пример:

```
class Student:
    def prepare_for_exam(self):
        print("И так сойдет")

class SessionStudent(Student):
    def pass_exam(self):
        super().prepare_for_exam()

student = SessionStudent()
student.pass_exam()

class TwoWeeksPreparation(Student):
    def prepare_for_exam(self):
        print("Ботал 2 недели")

class PreparedStudent(SessionStudent, TwoWeeksPreparation):
    pass

prepared_student = PreparedStudent()
prepared_student.pass_exam()
```

В результате `student` вызывает в `pass_exam` `prepare_for_exam` из класса `Student`, а `prepared_student` вызывает в `pass_exam` `prepare_for_exam` из класса `TwoWeeksPreparation`. Вначале я подумал, что всё дело в MRO, т.к. согласно `help(prepared_student)`

```
class PreparedStudent(SessionStudent, TwoWeeksPreparation)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      PreparedStudent
 |      SessionStudent
 |      TwoWeeksPreparation
 |      Student
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods inherited from SessionStudent:
 |  
 |  pass_exam(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from TwoWeeksPreparation:
 |  
 |  prepare_for_exam(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

у экземпляра `prepared_student` метод `prepare_for_exam` наследуется именно от `TwoWeeksPreparation`.
Во втором примере ситуация схожая:

```
class Robot:
    def fetch(self):
        print("Physical movement! Fetching")
    def move_up(self):
        print("Physical movement! Moving up")
    def move_down(self):
        print("Physical movement! Moving down")
    def move_right(self):
        print("Physical movement! Moving right")
    def move_left(self):
        print("Physical movement! Moving left")

class CleaningRobot(Robot):
    def clean(self):
        super().fetch()
        for i in range(10):
            super().move_up()
            super().move_down()
            super().move_right()
            super().move_left()
        print("End cleaning")

class MockRobot(Robot):
    def __init__(self):
        self.actions = []
    def move_up(self):
        self.actions.append("Up!")
    def move_down(self):
        self.actions.append("Down!")
    def move_right(self):
        self.actions.append("Right!")
    def move_left(self):
        self.actions.append("Left!")
    def fetch(self):
        self.actions.append("Fetch!")

class MockedCleaningBot(CleaningRobot, MockRobot):
    pass
mocked_robot = MockedCleaningBot()
mocked_robot.clean()
```

Однако здесь `mocked_robot` в методе `clean` вызывает методы родителя класса `CleaningRobot` - `Robot`, а не методы класса `MockRobot`, которые перегружены.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём различие этих примеров и почему поведение разное?

Comment: Как я знаю, последовательность наследований важна.. Есть класс A которая наследуется от классов B, C.. И у классов B и C есть одинаковый метод display(), если напишешь так A(B, C) а затем вызов метода display() то сработает вызов от класса C, а если A(C, B) то от класса B

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему порядок разрешения методов в python в примере работает именно так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995079/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-python-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Comment: Про порядок наследования, более мене стало яснее, но что насчёт super()? Разве super() без параметров не должен вызывать метод родительского класса? Возникает вопрос, родительский для какого?

Answer (score 1):

Опираясь на комментарии к посту сделал такую перестановочку:

```
class PreparedStudent(TwoWeeksPreparation, SessionStudent):
```

И вправду, теперь вывод выглядит вот так:

> И так сойдет\nИ так сойдет

Что говорит нам о том, что наследование от классов выполняется строго в обратном порядке явных родителей класса, рекомендую проделать то же с тремя и более родителями, в каждом из которых будут схожие методы, менять их местами и смотреть на результат

Comment: зачем задавать вопрос и забивать л о л

Comment: Я не забивал на вопрос. Он мне по прежнему интересен. Просто не было возможности разобраться. Касаемо вашего ответа: кто есть явные родители? Какова логика в super()? Метод, вызванный из наследника с помощью super() идёт далее вниз по списку mro? Т.е. для вашего примера mro имеет вид: (__main__.PreparedStudent,
 __main__.TwoWeeksPreparation,
 __main__.SessionStudent,
 __main__.Student,
 object). Метод pass_exam из класса SessionStudent, он вызывает super().prepare_for_exam() и ищет его далее по списку mro. Там далее по списку Student, у него то и есть prepare_for_exam.