# Проблема с множественным наследование в Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, наследование

```py
class classColumn:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m = 0.5
        self.a = 800 * self.m
        self.b = 500 * self.m
        self.tp = 190 * self.m
        self.x = 400
        self.y = 400
        super().__init__()

class Line:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ve=3
        print ("line")



class Moment_W(Line, classColumn):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        a=4+self.a
        print ("moment")
        print(self.ve)
        print(self.x)


#d=classColumn()
p=Moment_W()
```

В данном коде наследования атрибутов из ClassColumn не происходит.
Вопрос, что я делаю не так? Я до этого пробовал очень похожий код.  Немного другие имена переменных все работало. А тут голову сломал? может опечатка какая то я ее не вижу?

Comment: Нужно изменить порядок наследования, если Вы хотите иметь атрибут `a`: `Moment_W(classColumn, Line)`.

Comment: Да точно, или надо добавить super().__init__() в класс Line.  Блин, голову сломал что не так. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У обоих классов, от которых Вы наследуетесь, есть метод `__init__`. Чтобы не возникало вопросов, какой метод должна вызвать инструкция `super().__init__()`, придуманы алгоритмы разрешения порядка наследования.

В `Python` используется [алгоритм MRO С3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/995111/339283).

По этому алгоритму `super().__init__()` вызовет конструктор класса `Line`, и атрибут `self.a` не будет инициализирован, поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Вам нужно либо изменить порядок наследования, либо изменить сам конструктор.

---

Вы можете посмотреть полный порядок наследования с помощью метода `mro`:

```py
print(Moment_W.mro())
```

```py
[<class '__main__.Moment_W'>, <class '__main__.Line'>, <class '__main__.classColumn'>, <class 'object'>]
```